# Twisted exception when using ReturnValue

Tags: python, twisted

I`ve got this exception when using returnvalue in function

```
@inlineCallbacks    
def my_func(id):
  yield somefunc(id)

@inlineCallbacks
def somefunc(id):
  somevar = yield func(id) 
  returnValue(somevar)



returnValue(somevar)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1105, in returnValue
raise _DefGen_Return(val)
twisted.internet.defer._DefGen_Return:
```

The function works fine, but raises an exception.
How can i avoid this exception? I just need to return some value from the function.

Answer (score 1):

When using `inlineCallbacks` you must yield a deferred - in this case you the `yield` in `my_func` is yielding `func(id)` (which I assume is a deferred) but then is calling `returnValue` which is not allowed.

You can probably do something like:

```
@inlineCallbacks    
def my_func(id):
   somevar = yield somefunc(id)

@inlineCallbacks
def somefunc(id):
    yield func(id)
```

Comment: Look at this example http://hackedbellini.org/development/writing-asynchronous-python-code-with-twisted-using-inlinecallbacks/

It`s normal to yield and defer.returnvalue in the same function decorated as @inlineCallbacks

Answer (score 1):

`returnValue` uses exception trick to return value/s. 
It is normal, the exception will not cause any error.

Detail:
`@inlinecallback` decorator looks like

```
def decorator(...)
   try:
       .... (func call & other logics)
   except Exception as myExcept:
       return myExcept.values
```